# Can I reuse imports across modules of the same python package?

Tags: python, import, module, package, code-reuse

I have a package named "test" with several modules:

```
master/
|-- __init__.py
|-- app/
|-- auth/
|-- test/
|---- | __ init __.py
|---- | test_A.py
|---- | test_B.py
|---- | test_C.py
```

all test_X.py import the same core modules:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from master.app.app import create_app
from master.app.models import setup_db, subject_student, Subject, Student
from master.app.functions import query_a_record
```

I wonder if there is a way to create a single file that imports all of the above modules and imports that file into each test file. I am just trying to avoid code repetition.

**What I have tried:**

- Included all the imports in the __ init __.py file that is inside the test package then imported init into each test
- Created a config.py inside the package and then imported config into each module.

Of course, none of those have worked. Any suggestion as to how to write those imports just once and reuse that piece of code in all my test modules? Or that is not even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you delve a little bit in how Python defines and manages **namespaces**.

As for your question, `config.py` or `__init__.py` definitely import the required modules, but their names are tied to that namespace, so when you access any of those names within your `testX.py` scripts, it raises `NameError` because you're in a different namespace and that name is not recognized; you have to qualify it with the name of the module it belongs to.

A typical function call would be:

```
config.unittest.mock.patch()
```

You can easily avoid this qualification by importing all of `config` namespace:

```
from config import *
```

Comment: Thank you much @MaxShouman . That worked. In my case, I had to do

`from test.config import *`

So, before, I tried with just `import config` in test_X.py. The error I would get when running test_X was not from importing config but from missing modules such as "unittest" which was imported in config.py...Why would just `import config` not work? is that not implying "import * from config"?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped! Btw `import config` does exactly what `from config import *` does interpreter-wise but the former loads the module namespace as is, while the latter extracts all of the names in that namespace and adds them directly to the current namespace, allowing you to access them without qualification. Actually even if your first import is `from config import unittest`, the entire `config.py` is executed and loaded in memory, even though the non-imported objects are still unnamed, thus unaccessible.

Comment: As a side note, `from module import *` is not a good practice as it could create ambiguities when, for instance, you plan to use similar names in the calling script. Use that cautiously, e.g. when you know exactly what names you are importing, or when you explicitly specify the set of names that  `from module import *` would load by defining the `__all__` variable within the imported module.

Comment: got it @MaxShouman . I guess in this particular case I should be safe since I am not defining any functions or classes in config.py - just importing the core modules to run the tests. If I run into future problems, I guess I will guess where they are coming from.

Comment: @FernandoRodriguez yes in this case it's definitely safe.